# Listbox and case statement - store it in a database

Tags: vb.net

Before i begin i'd like to apologize if some things may be unclear but i try my best.
 Im using vb net to make a program that uses a listbox(and textboxes) and a case statement. Im trying to make a class that will later allow me to to send the user input into an access database. The problem im having is that i can't get the variable value that contains the case statement send to the database.

Here's the code, and possibly someone could help me resolve the problem:

This is what i have in the form that accepts the user input(it also contains textboxes but i have them figured out):

```
Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Fill Listbox with items
    Me.Controls.Add(ListBox1)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Shoot in-laws")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Become a paparazzi")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Drive 5 mph over speed limit")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Treat for rabies once a week")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Cheat on income taxes")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Breathe uder water")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Recite the Gettysburg Address")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Smile while being staked")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Stay calm while getting help on C#")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Day dream about playing chess")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Take candy from a baby")

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Select Case ListBox1.SelectedIndex
        Case 0
            dblTestScore = 50
        Case 1
            dblTestScore = 15
        Case 2
            dblTestScore = 25
        Case 3
            dblTestScore = 55
        Case 4
            dblTestScore = 10
        Case 5
            dblTestScore = 20
        Case 6
            dblTestScore = 40
        Case 7
            dblTestScore = 65
        Case 8
            dblTestScore = 30
        Case 9
            dblTestScore = 35
        Case 10
            dblTestScore = 45
    End Select

End Sub
```

Now the following code is in the class:

```
Public Class ClsWriteRecord
Public Sub addNewRecordMore(ByVal listTestScore As ListBox, ByVal listTEST As ListBox, 

'declare variables
Dim dblTestScore As Double
Dim strTEST As String

'Get values

strTEST = listTEST.GetItemText(listTEST.SelectedItem)
dblTestScore = listTEST.GetItemText(listTEST.SelectedIndex)

End Sub
End Class
```

The strTEST works properly and gets and sends listbox items to database(exampe "Shoot in-laws"), but dblTestScore doesnt. Instead values, for example 50,15, 25 etc it sends 0,1,2 which is the case number.

Could anyone help me figure it out? I search internet but couldnt find an answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you just great... Please see below...
This is your class you want to call from your main form or anywhere else you need it...

```
Public Class ClsWriteRecord

 Public Shared Function addNewRecordMore(ByVal listTestScore As Integer, ByVal listTEST As String)

    'Do your save routine here... and pass your information to it...'
    'Example...' Save(listTestScore, listTEST)
    'You would have to create the save function of course...'

 End Function

End Class
```

Then here is your main form or whatever else form you have...

```
 Public Class Form1

'Our global variables...'
Private dblTestScore As Integer = 0
Private strTest As String = String.Empty

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Put your items into an array then add this to the listbox...'
    Dim strItems As String() = {"Shoot in-laws", "Become a paparazzi", "Drive 5 mph over speed limit", "Treat for rabies once a week"} 'Add more as needed...'
    'Add your items...'
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(strItems)

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    'Set your variable for your text here...'
    strTest = ListBox1.SelectedItem

    'Build your case statement...'
    Select Case ListBox1.SelectedItem

        Case "Shoot in-laws"
            dblTestScore = 50
        Case "Become a paparazzi"
            dblTestScore = 15
        Case "Drive 5 mph over speed limit"
            dblTestScore = 25
        Case "Treat for rabies once a week"
            dblTestScore = 55
            'Continue your case on down here...'
    End Select

    'Call our function from other class We have our value and we have our text already...
    ClsWriteRecord.addNewRecordMore(dblTestScore, strTest)

End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks, let me know how it works out for you...